# Solve $ \frac{1}{xy} = \frac{x}{yz} + 1, \:\: \frac{1}{yz} = \frac{y}{zx} + 1, \:\: \frac{1}{zx} = \frac{z}{xy} + 1. $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

Solve the following system for positive integers:
$$ \frac{1}{xy} = \frac{x}{yz} + 1,  $$
$$ \frac{1}{yz} = \frac{y}{zx} + 1,  $$
$$ \frac{1}{zx} = \frac{z}{xy} + 1.  $$

---

**Attempt:**

Equivalent to

$$ z = x^{2} + xyz,  $$
$$ x = y^{2} + xyz,  $$
$$ y = z^{2} + xyz.  $$

Multiplying all:

$$ xyz = (x^{2}+xyz)(y^{2}+xyz)(z^{2}+xyz) = (xyz)^{2} + (xy)^{3}z + (xz)^{3}y + (yz)^{3}x + x^{4}(yz)^{2} + y^{4}(xz)^{2} + z^{4}(xy)^{2}  $$

Comment: $$\begin{align*}
z &= x^{2} + xyz
\\ \implies z(1-xy)&=x^2
\\ \implies (1-xy)&>0
\end{align*}$$
Which is not possible for any positive integers $x$ and $y$

Comment: In any of the equations, $LHS \le 1$ while $RHS >1$ for positive integers, so even individually they don't have solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We see that the first equation is equivalent to:

$$\frac{1}{xy} = \frac{x}{yz} + 1\ \Rightarrow z = x^{2}+xyz \ \Rightarrow z(1-xy) = x^{2}$$

Since $x^{2}$ and $z$ are positive, we must have $1-xy > 0$. However, since $x$ and $y$ are positive integers, this is impossible, so the system has no solution. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Then you can just give only one of those equations and ask to solve because no use of giving all three.